# Haystack - 'SearchQuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I am trying to serialize haystack result,

**api.py**

```
class PinSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = Pin.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PinSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        queryset = EmptySearchQuerySet()
        if request.GET.get('q') is not None:
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            queryset = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
        return queryset
```

**serializer.py**

```
class PinSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pin
        fields = ('id', 'office_name', 'pin_code', 'office_type', 'delivery_status',
                  'division_name', 'region_name', 'circle_name', 'taluk', 'district', 'state')
```

but I got the following error,

> 'SearchQuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'

Answer (score 2):

The serializer expect **pin** objects but you are returning **SearchResut** objects

Try this

```
class PinSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = Pin.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PinSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        queryset = EmptySearchQuerySet()
        if request.GET.get('q') is not None:
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            queryset = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query).models(Pin)
        return [i.object for i in queryset]
```

I also specified **pin** model in the **searchQuerySet**

Comment: But I'm not exactly sure about the error you specified. Maybe you tried SearchQuerySet().model()?